# Event binding with Static Ancestors leads to every click event being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, uielement

I Created a small test application that should allow the user to create:

- create list elements
- remove list elements
- create lists
- remove lists

I learned that dynamically added elements don't get an event bound to them (based on this: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) ) so I tried to attach the event on a single static ancestor. Unfortunately, this leads to every single click event being triggered when just one button was pressed.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="listContainer">
            <ol>
                <li>First list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li>
                <li>First list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li>
                <li>First list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li>
            </ol>
            <button class="btnAddListElement">+Add List Item</button>
            <button class="btnDeleteList">Delete List</button>
        </div>
        <button class="btnAddList">+Add List</button>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
var btnDeleteListItem = $(".btnDeleteListItem");
var btnAddListElement = $(".btnAddListElement");
var btnDeleteList = $(".btnDeleteList");
var btnAddList = $(".btnAddList");
var container = $("#container");

container.on("click",btnDeleteListItem, function (e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    console.log("list item deleted");
});

container.on("click",btnAddListElement, function (e) {
    var html = '<li> Just added <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li>';
    $("ol").append(html);
    console.log("list item added");
});

container.on("click",btnDeleteList, function (e) {
    $(this).parent().remove();
    console.log("list deleted");
});

btnAddList.on("click", function(e){
    var html = '<div class="listContainer"><ol><li>Other list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li><li>Other list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li><li>Other list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li></ol><button class="btnAddListElement">+Add List Item</button><button class="btnDeleteList">Delete List</button></div>';
    $(html).insertBefore($(this));
    console.log("list added");
});
</script>

</html>`
```

Is there a way to segregate the click events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because, although you're using delegated event handlers, you're only selecting the elements on load of the DOM. To fix this pass the selector argument to `on()` as a string. That way the selector will be matched as the `click` events bubble through the `#container`, not just for specific element instances.

Also note that you need to make the `append()` call *only* on the `ol` which is relative to the `.btnAddListElement` button which was clicked, otherwise you end up adding a new `li` to every list. To do this, change `$('ol')` to `$(this).prev('ol')`.

```js
var $container = $("#container");

$container.on("click", ".btnDeleteListItem", function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  console.log("list item deleted");
});

$container.on("click", '.btnAddListElement', function(e) {
  var html = '<li> Just added <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li>';
  $(this).prev("ol").append(html);
  console.log("list item added");
});

$container.on("click", '.btnDeleteList', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  console.log("list deleted");
});

$container.on('click', '.btnAddList', function(e) {
  var html = '<div class="listContainer"><ol><li>Other list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li><li>Other list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li><li>Other list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li></ol><button class="btnAddListElement">+Add List Item</button><button class="btnDeleteList">Delete List</button></div>';
  $(html).insertBefore($(this));
  console.log("list added");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="listContainer">
    <ol>
      <li>First list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li>
      <li>First list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li>
      <li>First list <button class="btnDeleteListItem">Delete</button></li>
    </ol>
    <button class="btnAddListElement">+Add List Item</button>
    <button class="btnDeleteList">Delete List</button>
  </div>
  <button class="btnAddList">+Add List</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought I was making my code cleaner by not using the string based selector argument. Also, thank you for pointing out that `$(this).prev('ol')` it would have taken me a lifetime to find that one out.

Comment: Glad to help. For reference, in most situations caching selectors is a good thing, but not when working with delegated events.